# How to replace only capturing group in Regex.Replace?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, .net-3.5

I have dictionary with key as pattern and replacement as value. Each pattern have one capturing group. I would like to replace ONLY capturing group with the replacement. My attempt is the following, but of course it's replacing whole pattern. I am limited to .NET 3.5. Not sure if I am on right track.

```
        string xml = "abc def ghi blabla horse 123 jakljd alj ldkfj s;aljf kljf sdlkj flskdjflskdjlf lskjddhcn guffy";
        Dictionary<string, string> substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string> 
        { 
            {"abc (.+) ghi", "AAA"},
            {"kljf (.+) flskdjflskdjlf", "BBB"}
        };

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in substitutions)
        {
            xml = Regex.Replace(xml, entry.Key, delegate(Match m) { return m.Groups[1].Value; });
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
        }
```

The final string should like this:

```
"abc AAA ghi blabla horse 123 jakljd alj ldkfj s;aljf BBB sdlkj flskdjflskdjlf lskjddhcn guffy"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive [loohbehind and lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
string xml = "abc def ghi blabla horse 123 jakljd alj ldkfj s;aljf kljf sdlkj flskdjflskdjlf lskjddhcn guffy";
Dictionary<string, string> substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{ 
    {@"(?<=abc\s).+(?=\sghi)", "AAA"},
    {@"(?<=kljf\s).+(?=\sflskdjflskdjlf)", "BBB"}
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in substitutions)
{
    xml = Regex.Replace(xml, entry.Key, entry.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(xml);
}
```

They are zero-width assertions, *i.e.*, they are required to satisfy the match, but won't be included in the result.

Comment: This basically the same what vks suggests.

Comment: Isnt this the same as my answer?

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, the idea is the same, however I started writing this answer about 30 seconds after the question was asked, and I usually take my time writing a relatively complete answer, disliking the fastest gun in the west approach, and during that time fast guns might shoot an answer with the same concept, however I still post my answer when I'm done FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `lookarounds`.

```
"(?<=abc ).+(?= ghi)", "AAA"
```

This will enable you to replace the words you want.You dont need capture group